# String.format() get maximum value

Tags: java, string, integer, format

I implemented a counter method that returns always an incremented number. But the user can give wished [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), 2 digits, 3 digits or whatever he wants. 
The format is the standard String.format() type of String like `%02d` or `%5d`. When the maximum value is reached, the counter should be reset to 0.

**How can I find out the max value that can be represented with the given [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)?**

```
int counter = 0;
private String getCounter(String format){
    if(counter >= getMaximum(format)){
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
    }
    return String.format(format, counter);
}

private int getMaximum(String format){
    //TODO ???
    //Format can be %02d => should return 100
    //Format can be %05d => should return 100000

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't validated this code, but something along the lines of this should work with erro checking in place

```
    String str = fullresultText.replace ("%", "").replace("d", "");
    maxVal = Math.pow (10, Integer.parseInt (str));
```

Comment: This should work, but will it be compatible with other format expressions too? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: For my case this is maybe the fastest and easiest way. Just got a problem if other characters are mentioned in the format

Comment: Thanks, I thought that we were talking about integers, hence the masks of %02d etc.  Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing builtin for this, and I'm not aware of any libraries that do this (I could be wrong).  Remember that formats will expand if necessary to avoid losing digits.  For example

```
System.out.printf("%06d", 11434235);
```

will happily print the entire 8-digit number.

So specifying the format directly is probably not the right approach.  Create a `Counter` class to encapsulate the desired "odometer" behavior.

```
public class Counter {
    private int width;
    private int limit;
    private String format;
    private int value=0;
    public Counter(int width, int value) { 
        this.width  = width; 
        this.limit  = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(width).intValue()-1; 
        this.format = String.format("%%0%dd",width);
        this.value  = value;
    }
    public Counter(int width) {
        this(width,0);
    }
    public Counter increment() { 
        value = value<limit ? value+1 : 0;
        return this; 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(this.format,this.value); 
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Counter c3 = new MiscTest.Counter(3,995);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(c3.increment().toString());
}
```

Output:

```
996
997
998
999
000
001
002
003
004
005
```

Comment: Well that's my point, when %03d is given, 999 returns 999, 1000 returns 1000, but I only want 3 digits.

Comment: You want to throw away data? For `%03d` what do you want to display for value 1234? `123`? `234`?

Comment: Jim: I would like to do the same and display 234 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int counter = 0;

private String getCounter(String format) {
    counter = (counter + 1) % getMaximum(format);
    return String.format(format, counter);
}

private int getMaximum(String format) {
    try {
        MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("%{0,number,integer}d");
        int pow = ((Long) messageFormat.parse(format)[0]).intValue();
        return (int) Math.pow(10, pow);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect format");
        return -1;
    }
}
```