# how to restrict the Formatter from expanding

Tags: java, formatter

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuffer());
f.format("%06d",11434235);
System.out.println(f);
```

prints the value `11434235`

is there any way to restrict the `Formatter` from expanding the output?

that is, the output should be `114342` instead of `11434235` when the format string is `"%06d"`

Comment: your classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110103/string-format-get-maximum-value/19110210#19110210

Comment: @user2310289 : i am no student mate.. :) i posted it out of curiosity...

Comment: Oh I see, using the same value of `11434235` confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply format this as a `String`, so I think the best solution using `format()` will be

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuffer());
f.format("%.6s",11434235);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround:

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuffer());
f.format("%06d", 11434235);
System.out.println(f.toString().substring(0, 6));
```

See Eel Lee's solution for a solution with just a format string.

Comment: good approach mate, just have a doubt, why do we need format statement in your code, because 'substring(0, 6)' will provide the solution right?

Comment: The format blows it up to six digits even for smaller numbers.

Comment: Well, in fact it's possible to specify such a cut, check my answer.